# Visual Studio : Make files in a folder got to bin/debug and not bin/debug/folder

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-ce

Consider This:

I have folder called \SQLCE35Dlls inside my solution. It has some dlls that are required for application to interact with a SQLCE database in a stand alone fashion [without sql server ce 35 install on the PC].

After a build, I want these files to go to bin/debug and not to bin/debug/SQLCE35Dlls/. Setting "Copy if Newer" creates the latter situation. I want the former.

Is it possible to facilitate this or does this have to done as part of the installer script? 
[avoiding the solution of adding the dlls at the root level of the solution instead of inside a folder].

This is a Winforms project solution.

Comment: See also:" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53449893/visual-studio-post-build-event-how-to-copy-files-to-output-bin-directory-on?noredirect=1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform any custom file copying operations by adding a **post-build** event command. Look at the **Build Events** tab of the project properties page.

Create the command using the **xcopy** command and the appropriate built-in macros. Click the **Edit Post-build** button to see the macros.

example:

```
xcopy $(TargetDir)\SQLCE35Dlls $(TargetDir)
```

This should copy all the files from **bin\debug\SQLCE35Dlls** to **bin\debug**.

Comment: Thanks Charles, that did it. I ended up using the following to avoid 2 copies of the .dlls floating around.



MOVE /Y $(TargetDir)\SQL35ReqDlls\*.dll $(TargetDir)